# JavaFX -- Button action causing large string of errors

Tags: java, javafx

I'm still incredibly new to JavaFX and currently learning from online tutorials. I've been trying to build a calculator for a class project and, for the most part, it appears to work... until the clear button is pressed. Once pressed, the clear button causes all the operator buttons to no longer function and when a user attempts to click one, I receive a very large string of errors.

Here is this error list:

```
    Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1774)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$ControllerMethodEventHandler.handle(FXMLLoader.java:1657)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:86)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:49)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Node.fireEvent(Node.java:8411)
    at javafx.scene.control.Button.fire(Button.java:185)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.behavior.ButtonBehavior.mouseReleased(ButtonBehavior.java:182)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:96)
    at com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.BehaviorSkinBase$1.handle(BehaviorSkinBase.java:89)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler$NormalEventHandlerRecord.handleBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:218)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventHandler.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventHandler.java:80)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:238)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventHandlerManager.dispatchBubblingEvent(EventHandlerManager.java:191)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.CompositeEventDispatcher.dispatchBubblingEvent(CompositeEventDispatcher.java:59)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:58)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.BasicEventDispatcher.dispatchEvent(BasicEventDispatcher.java:56)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventDispatchChainImpl.dispatchEvent(EventDispatchChainImpl.java:114)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEventImpl(EventUtil.java:74)
    at com.sun.javafx.event.EventUtil.fireEvent(EventUtil.java:54)
    at javafx.event.Event.fireEvent(Event.java:198)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.process(Scene.java:3757)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$MouseHandler.access$1500(Scene.java:3485)
    at javafx.scene.Scene.impl_processMouseEvent(Scene.java:1762)
    at javafx.scene.Scene$ScenePeerListener.mouseEvent(Scene.java:2494)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:352)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler$MouseEventNotification.run(GlassViewEventHandler.java:275)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.lambda$handleMouseEvent$355(GlassViewEventHandler.java:388)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.runWithoutRenderLock(QuantumToolkit.java:389)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.GlassViewEventHandler.handleMouseEvent(GlassViewEventHandler.java:387)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.handleMouseEvent(View.java:555)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.View.notifyMouse(View.java:937)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$null$149(WinApplication.java:191)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:71)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor1.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:275)
    at javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader$MethodHandler.invoke(FXMLLoader.java:1769)
    ... 48 more
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
    at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
    at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
    at calc.Controller.processOperators(Controller.java:46)
    ... 58 more
```

Here are my .java classes:

```
//MAIN CLASS

package calc;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.event.EventHandler;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;





public class Main extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

        try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/calc/Main.fxml"));    
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
//        scene.getStylesheets().add(getClass().getResource("calc.css").toExternalForm());
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    } catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    }

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}




// CONTROLLER CLASS 

package calc;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;



public class Controller {
    @FXML
    private Label result;
    private float number1 = 0;
    private String operator = "";
    private boolean start = true;
    private Model model = new Model();



    @FXML
    public void processNumbers(ActionEvent event){
        if (start) {
            result.setText("");
            start = false;
        }
        String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();
        result.setText(result.getText()+value);
    }

    @FXML
    public void processOperators(ActionEvent event){
        String value = ((Button)event.getSource()).getText();

        if(!value.equals("=")){
            if(!operator.isEmpty())
                return;

            operator = value;
            number1 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText());
            result.setText("");
        } else {
            if(operator.isEmpty())
                return;
            float number2 = Float.parseFloat(result.getText());
            float output = model.Calculate(number1, number2, operator);
            result.setText(String.valueOf(output));
            operator = "";
            start = true;
        } }


         @FXML
         public void processClear(ActionEvent event){

            result.setText("");

    }  

}





// MODEL CLASS

package calc;

/**
 *
 * @author valentyne
 */
public class Model {
    public float Calculate(float number1, float number2, String operator) {
       switch(operator) {
           case "+":
               return number1 + number2;
           case "-":
               return number1 - number2;
           case "*":
               return number1 * number2;
           case "/":
               if(number2 == 0)
                   return 0;
               return number1 / number2;

           default:
               return 0;
       }    

    }

}
```

And here is my FXML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.effect.*?>
<?import javafx.geometry.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.text.*?>
<?import java.lang.*?>
<?import java.util.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.*?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.*?>

<VBox alignment="CENTER" maxHeight="390.0" maxWidth="300.0" minHeight="390" minWidth="300" prefHeight="390.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0" style="-fx-background-color: e1ffa7; -fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-border-width: 3; -fx-background-image: url(/calc/starbg.jpg); -fx-background-repeat: repeat;" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="calc.Controller">
   <children>
      <StackPane prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="200.0">
         <children>
            <Label fx:id="result" opacity="0.75" prefHeight="27.0" prefWidth="233.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-border-width: 1; -fx-padding: 5px; -fx-background-color: dafb9b;" textAlignment="RIGHT" textFill="#63861a" StackPane.alignment="TOP_CENTER">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
               <StackPane.margin>
                  <Insets />
               </StackPane.margin>
            </Label>
         </children>
      </StackPane>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="7" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="8" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="9" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="/" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="4" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="5" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="6" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="*" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="1" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="2" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="3" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="-" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
      <HBox alignment="CENTER" prefHeight="50.0" prefWidth="300.0" spacing="10.0">
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processNumbers" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="0" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processClear" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="C" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="=" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#processOperators" opacity="0.75" prefWidth="50.0" style="-fx-border-style: solid; -fx-border-color: afd95e; -fx-background-color: d2fe7e;" text="+" textFill="#63861a">
               <font>
                  <Font size="18.0" />
               </font>
            </Button>
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

Any ideas as to what is causing this to happen?

Comment: Does your editor/IDE have debugging capability? If so, have you tried stepping through the functionality to see what is happening? Consider your explanation of the problem. You clear the text field and then click an operator. What is the code doing across that sequence of actions? Consider the output from the Exception stack `Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String at ...(FloatingDecimal.java:1842)
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseFloat(FloatingDecimal.java:122)
at java.lang.Float.parseFloat(Float.java:451)
at calc.Controller.processOperators(Controller.java:46)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The exception says it all:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
```

which happens in:

```
Float.parseFloat(result.getText());
```

Basically you should rework your logic. You e. g. don't reset the operator during the clear operation.